# SBT unresolved dependency: com.paypal.sdk#paypal-core;LATEST

Tags: maven, jar, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a play framework 2.3.10 project and it can't find a paypal dependency. I suspect that it's due to the `LATEST` version tag (maybe it's a maven special version tag not supported by SBT?).

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.paypal.sdk#paypal-core;LATEST: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.paypal.sdk#paypal-core;LATEST: not found
```

We're not including this version directly, but it's a dependency of another dependency: `com.paypal.sdk#merchantsdk;2.13.117`.

Do you know how to solve this? Should we exclude the LATEST version and include a specific one (how?), or is there a way to include that LATEST dependency?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I excluded core dependency from merchant and manually added core with the latest version.

"com.paypal.sdk" % "merchantsdk" % "2.14.117" exclude ("com.paypal.sdk","paypal-core"),
 "com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.7.0",